# Trouble installing visual studio code on fedora 12

Tags: fedora-12

Does visual studio code work on fedora 12? Looking for better install directions as I don't understand the directions on https://code.visual.com any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's Fedora 12? 31 was just released.

Comment: Yes, really old

Comment: You download and install the rpm.